# How to use open file dialog in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Please help me, I want to pick the pdf file locally in xamarin forms(cross platform). So on a button click i need to open the file dialog to pick pdf file locally.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? How about posting some code or similar ? This page is not a codemill please edit your question and show some effort. Than we will gladly help you to fix your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view PDF file using Xamarin Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820246/how-to-view-pdf-file-using-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 7):

This is not something that can be done in a true cross-platform way. For example; on iOS you cannot access the filesystem directly, while on Android and UWP you can.

I have created a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.Filepicker) Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker ([Github](https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows)) (original by [rafaelrmou](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows)), which tries to solve this for you. On iOS you need iCloud Drive to be configured.

If you do not want to use the plugin you could always look into the code and roll your own.

Comment: It works on Xamarin.Android not in Xamarin.Form. Please confirm?

Comment: You mean iOS instead of Forms?

Comment: No. I am talking about Xamarin.Form. It didn't work on Xamarin.Forms. https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/issues/41

Comment: This library is built for Xamarin.Forms, so I’m not sure what you mean by it’s working on Xamarin.Android and not on Forms

Comment: is there some kind of documentation whatsoever? Or steps on how to use this library?

Comment: Not much, but there is this: https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/