# Xamarin.forms display PDF in webview not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I download a pdf stream from my server. In my app I save the bytearray to a the local folder as pdf. But when I open it in the webview, it just shows a white page.

I followed this example: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf.

Here is customwebview in my xaml:

```
<local:CustomWebView x:Name="customView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Here is my code of the custom view:

```
 public class CustomWebView : WebView
    {        
        public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
       returnType: typeof(string),
       declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
       defaultValue: default(string));

        public string Uri
            {
                get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
                set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
            }
    }
```

This is my method to retrieve the pdf byte array and store it locally:

```
 private async void ReadPDF()
        {
            var response = CommonLibrary.Helpers.HTTPClientHelper.DownloadPDF(AccountBL.AccessToken, APISettings.APIURI("api/booking/pdf"));
            var streamContent = response.Content as System.Net.Http.StreamContent;
            var bytes = CommonLibrary.Helpers.FileHelper.ReadBytes(await streamContent.ReadAsStreamAsync());
            var dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var fileName = "test.pdf";
            CommonLibrary.Helpers.FileHelper.WriteFileFromByteArray(bytes, dir, fileName);

           customView.Uri = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, fileName);            
        }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried getting your webview to go to a website, just to ensure whether it's a loading issue or a display issue?

Comment: Hi Jaxi, you are right. A normal site is not loaded also. You have to just set the customWebview.Uri am I correct?

Comment: Hi Jaxi, A normal site is loaded when I set the the source property -> customView.Source = "http://www.google.nl". When I set the source to the pdf location it's not working.

Comment: Can you breakpoint and see if the dir variable is actually populated with a directory?

Comment: I did and it's populated and I can find the file via the device monitor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can display a "remote" PDF in a webview on iOS.
With Android there are some problems. I suggest to take a look to this repo [OpenPDF](https://github.com/acaliaro/OpenPdf). I use a CustomRenderer and a google tool to display the PDF. I have had some problems with some Android version... but you can take a look.(here a [blog](https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/11/30/open-a-pdf-inside-a-webview-in-xamarin-forms-android/))

Otherwise there is @AdamPedley suggestion to use PDF JS Viewer [Adam Pedley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666292/best-way-to-open-a-remote-pdf-in-xamarin-forms-pcl-project/43670065#43670065)
The code is [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/).

This is the CustomRenderer for Android

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace DisplayPDF.Droid
{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);

            if (e.NewElement != null) {
                var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
                Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                Control.LoadUrl (string.Format ("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format ("file:///android_asset/Content/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode (customWebView.Uri))));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and openpdf is the way to go, but I'm experiencing some problems. Is it only working with a portable project? I have a shared project in my solution.

Comment: I think it can work in a Shared Project without problem. It's only a WebView's Custom Renderer

Comment: Hi Alessandro, I don't think I understand how this works. I have tried to create the renderer in the shared project without any succes. Where should I put this renderer? Is this only working for Android? I also want it to work for IOS? I don't understand the concept of the renderer. Could you please try and help me step by step? Thanks in advance. And happy xmas.

Comment: @Yaza, there is a repo in the post. Yes, it is only for Android because iOS should works without problem using webview. You can take a look also to this solution https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/showing-pdf-files-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Hi Alessandro, thank you that worked perfectly. Thank you for your effort. I'm sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2):

Following approach will allow you to view pdf in xamarin forms. If you are trying to open one from azure blob or you have valid URl.

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
var page = new ContentPage();
webView.Source = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://yourpdfurl.pdf";
page.Content = webView;
Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
```

Comment: Will this work for both Android and iOS also from local path?

Comment: This works if you have valid URL for your PDF and you need to replace 
"url=http://yourpdfurl.pdf "  with PDF url. I have used azure blob storage to store the PDF's.