# Rendering HTML in Xamarin Forms and opening embedded PDF from the HTML link

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have written HTML file which contains link to some other websites. I used

```
HtmlWebViewSource html = new HtmlWebViewSource();
```

to render and display HTML contents.

Now, I have links of URLs in that HTML and when I click the link, it opens default browser and opens the website. I used:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri(args.Url));
```

Now, the problem is I would like to have a link in that HTML and upon clicking that link, it should open embedded PDF file.

Is there any way I could achieve this from my code design OR do I have to re-write different approach. And if any best approach available, can you please suggest it?

[image]

Comment: You appear to already know how to render HTML and intercept a link click from a webview.  So are you just asking how to open a PDF?

Comment: Yes. How do i put link to PDF file inside HTML? I could just put the link there but Device.Uri will thrown an error if I do that.

Comment: your link handler can check if the url is a PDF and call a PDF viewer instead.  There are already many existing questions that address different methods to display a PDF in your app

Answer (score 3):

In iOS, you can use [WKWebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/webview#wkwebview) or [QLPreviewController](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/previewing-files-with-xamarin-ios/) or load pdf files.

In Android, you can open the pdf file through:

```
    Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
    intent.SetDataAndType(uri, application);
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset | ActivityFlags.NewTask);

    Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

You need to create a [dependency-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/) and implement the open pdf method in each platform project. Then call it when click `openpdf link` in Xamarin.forms project.

Here are several threads you can check:

[opening-a-pdf-with-xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286406/opening-a-pdf-with-xamarin-forms)

[how-to-open-pdf-or-txt-file-in-default-app-on-xamarin-forms](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103042/how-to-open-pdf-or-txt-file-in-default-app-on-xamarin-forms)

[how-to-view-pdf-file-using-xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820246/how-to-view-pdf-file-using-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a [webview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows) in order to not change your code too much, and works very good, just see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833809/xamarin-forms-display-pdf-in-webview-not-working) first. Otherwise, there are some third party paid frameworks like [Telerik](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/pdfviewer/pdfviewer-overview) with great controls.